# How to create a cron job that executes shell script that writes in text file

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-10.04, cron-task

I have created a Shell Script as below

**Sample.sh**

```
  echo "Hi there"
```

I also added cron job in cron tab which is under /etc/crontab as below

```
* * * * * /home/Sample.sh > /home/Sample.txt
```

I have created the Sample.txt file in /home/ directory.

I have also checked the permission for read and write for both the file

When I execute the Sample.sh file it works fine.it writes in Sample.txt file

Now I don't understand why it is not writing in the Text file from the cron task i scheduled

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Please Help me in fixing this issue

Comment: Did you check your cron daemon is running? As a side note, your '* * * * *' means you want an execution every minute. Is that what you want?

Comment: It overwrites the file on each run, are you sure you don't want `>>` instead?

Comment: `/home` is a weird place for your stuff anyway, it would normally be `/home/username`.

Answer (score 0):

The first maybe you can script invocation at the top e.g. `#!/bin/sh`. Its required in file bash.

After you can run as:

```
* * * * * bash /home/Sample.sh > /home/Sample.txt
```

If you run not okey. You can check  [stackoverflow.com/11932056#11932056](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932014/how-to-run-a-shell-script-by-cron-job/11932056#11932056)