# BASH - Most efficient method of setting this script as a timed/routine event?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I've recently started a simple project, just to help me learn the BASH scripting language a little better. Anyway, this script is set to alternate/rotate the user's desktop background/wallpaper at a given interval.

Given that this task would most likely be done every 30 minutes to 1 hour, how should I go about doing this. Would 30 minute/1 hour timers be very inefficient? Or, could cronjobs do a better job for me?

Also, how could I get this script to run in the background, so that a terminal window is not always required to be open?

Could you provide some sort of an idea into the syntax, if you can, as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932014/how-to-run-a-shell-script-by-cron-job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a suitable job for `cron`. `cron` would take care of invoking the script at regular intervals. You would not then have to be concerned in your script when the script should run and managing a script running in the background.

Running in the background would be extravagent as the script does not need to do much - not much more than change the current desktop setting. Typically the script would only take a small fraction of a second to complete the task.

`cron` entries have six fields-:

```
 mins hours day  month day-of-week path_to_command
 0-59 0-23  1-31 1-12      0-6      command
days of the week start on Sunday. 0=Sunday, 1=Monday etc.
```

`cron` entry to run the script every hour for all days and months-:

```
0 * * * * /path/change_wallpaper.sh
```

to list your current `cron` jobs, type

```
 crontab -l
```

Edit your cron jobs and add the new cron entry-:

```
 crontab -e
```

Check the new setting is in place -:

```
 crontab -l
```

Comment: Thanks I'll combine both your answers. That should sort it out for me.

Comment: Any reason why you dont use `crontab -e`?

Comment: I still had my old solaris blinkers on :) thanks will revise post.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how could I get this script to run in the background, so that a terminal window is not always required to be open?

That would be a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29). And there's no need to write your own. It's a bit tedious in bash if you want [pidfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain), `start`|`stop`|`restart` etc. Just add a new cronjob which'll execute your script every `n` minute or something.

**Edit your cronjobs**

```
crontab -e
```

**Execute script every 30 min:** (not the same as `30`, which would do it every `hh:30`!)

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/your/script
```

**Restart cron. How depends on distro, here's Ubuntu:**

```
service cron restart
```

**List cronjobs:**

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll combine your two answers, should really help.

Comment: @user2298964 I updated my answer, I was incorrect with the timing. It should be `*/30` to execute every 30 minute. Just `30` would be every time it's `hh:30` (half-something).

Answer (score 0):

I would personally run the script using following crontab:

```
0 * * * * $HOME/changewallpaper.sh
```

which you can install as a user with this command

```
crontab -e
```

Other solutions include running daemon script from file ~/.xprofile

For more information please refer to

```
man crontab
man 5 crontab
```

Also check out this project [Variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/).